# use of foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

, If I have (`A,B,C)` as PK in parent table and `(B,C)`[unique] are foreign keys and Primary Key in child table with delete cascade enabled, If I delete a record containing (B,C) from parent table will that delete all the records from child table?

Comment: isn't it easy to try?

Comment: @ykaganovich I agree but the problem is Workbench is allowing me to insert anything in any column thus not checking constraints etc i thnk

Comment: it depends on what RDBMS it is and whether you use `CASCADE` deletes

Comment: Do you realise that all the confusion in the comments could have been avoided by putting **the real DDL in the question** ?

Comment: @wildplasser I just explained the schema ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Definition a Forign Key has to be the same as the PK that it refers to. Your columns in the child table (B,C) **do not match** the PK of the parent table (A,B,C) and therefore cannot be considered an FK back to that parent.

Cascading deletes will have no impact where a FK-->>PK relationship does not exist, which is the case here, so the answer is no.

Comment: that is strange to know, even If i have uique constraint on (B,C)?

Comment: Think about it this way, FK's should tell you 1 thing, and only 1 thing, about the current (child) record. If you join from Child to Parent on (B,C) you can potentially get multiple results as (B,C) is not unique on the parent.

Comment: (to the OP) if {B,C} is unique in the parent table, then {A} is functionally dependent on it and the PK={B,C,A} would make no sense. BTW: instead of the fuzzy text you could put the DDL in your yestion.

Comment: @wildplasser I agree this is the bad design

Comment: @wildplasser is correct. Either (A,B,C) is not the correct key (because (B,C) is the real key, or else you cannot enforce the FK.

Comment: @Declan_K i agree thta wildplasser is right,my point here is the (B,C) also uniquely identify each row, so they can do the cascade delete function? notice (B,C) is Pk and FK in my child table

Comment: The question is - Does (B,C) uniquely identify each row in the PARENT table?

Comment: Then make (B,C) the PK of the Parent table and your problem is solved.

Comment: @Declan_K will do that , but as per the working of how SQL works, what if we have (A,B,C) as PK in the parent table..

Comment: "if we have (A,B,C) as PK in the parent table.." -  It won't work, as I stated in the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately: it _will_ work. Consider the PK={ssn,zipcode,dob}. It will work (but makes no sense) A UNIQUE constraint on {zipcode,dob} will work, too (depends on the data, obviously) An FK of {zipcode,dob} to a zipcode_birthdate-table would work, too. ...  but it would make no sense. (unless .. 4NF comes to mind ;-)